Advice on using travel agents for accommodation and transportation in Istanbul
I am looking for accommodations for a trip to Istanbul. The airport is a distance away from the main city center, and I'm weighing the options between taking a taxi (which I understand can have unpredictable charges) and renting a car (not to drive into the city center like Sultanahmet or Beyoglu, but just to get to the periphery, like Ortakoy or Uskudar).
With the widely varying prices and locations of hotels and Airbnbs, optimizing plans on your own seems like it can be daunting if you don't have local knowledge. Is it advisable to use local travel agents? Is that a practical option outside of going with pre-planned packaged tours?

We are not a travel agency, so this question might not be quite appropriate.
That said, your options will vary based on which airport you arrive at.
Renting a car seems like a bad idea, unless you are likely to need/use the car during your stay, not just to get into town. You will, after all, have to drop off the car after you've used it.
I'm not a fan of Uber, and don't use them if/when I can. But, Uber does cover Istanbul, and an airport taxi through Uber tends to be reliable, and will tell you the cost of the ride upfront.
Public transport, depending on your arrival time, can be an excellent option. Both airports are connected by Metro, though SAW is a bit tougher to get into Europe from.
Adding a note on using local travel agents; Yeah, travel planning can be daunting when it's your first time. But it's also never been easier. For many, the planning is part of the joy of travel; Figure out what area you'd like to stay in, check Booking.com, AirBnB (or whatever you fancy) for accommodation. Compare places and prices. Outsourcing this 'work' is easy, but you'll pay for it, and you will have to rely on someone else's opinion on what is good and bad, as well as their interpretation of your wishes.

FWIW, Uber at IST last year was weird, they don't seem to be authorized to pick up at the airport so we had to furtively duck into the Arrivals area and the driver seemed very worried about getting caught.  And it cost more than a regular taxi on the way back.
